# Force Reload Image in Web Browser

Tags: google-chrome

I found that sometimes an image won't load fully on my browser, and when I press `F5`, instead of refetching the image from the server, the browser reloads it from the cache. Is there anyway to force the server to resend the image?

**Edit: I am using Google Chrome.**

**Note: But I am speaking here as an end Internet user, not as a developer. So the idea to modify the HTML to put in a random number doesn't work here.**

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome is the browser that I'm using

Comment: @Justin: good answer. Why not repost your point as a real answer instead of a comment. In that way I can upvote you and accept your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On many browsers, pressing Control-F5 will reload the page and bypass the cache.  The Wikipedia "[Bypass your cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache)" page has details for all modern web browsers.

For Chrome, it appears that as of this writing there is a confirmed bug where it will sometimes not bypass cache when reloading with Ctrl+F5 as it is documented. The only option for now is to clear the cache completely, then reload the page. Here's some discussion of the issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=603

Answer (score 0):

What I've done when the wrong image gets cached is select 'View Image' or the like so I get a page/tab/window with just the image and then shift-reload that guaranteeing that particular image gets reloaded.